# Change of the order of integration in a multiple integral

Tags: integration

I was solving a physics problem when I found a multiple integral with this form:

$$I_{n}(x,y) = \int ^{y}_{x} dx_{n} \int_{x}^{x_{n}} dx_{n-1} \cdots \int_{x}^{x_{2}} dx_{1}\ f(x_{1}, ..., x_{n})$$

I would like to know if I can change the order of integration such that I integrate first in $x_{n}$, after in $x_{n-1}$, and so on.

$$I_{n}(x,y) = \int  dx_{1}  \cdots \int dx_{n}\ f(x_{1}, ..., x_{n}),$$

and, if the answer is yes, what would be the limits of integration? (I could solve this if $n =2$, but with an arbitrary $n$ everything gets more confusing)
.

Comment: $$I_n(x,y)=\int_x^y dx_1\int_{x_1}^y dx_2\ldots\int_{x_{n-1}}^y dx_n\,f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$ (and a [traditional reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) regarding conditions on f, perhaps out of concern in your context).

Comment: Thank you! I read your reference and now I don't know if my function have the necessary conditions to apply Fubini's theorem. Actually, in my problem $$f(x_{i}) = e^{-ia_{n}(x_{n} -x_{n-1})} e^{-ia_{n-1}(x_{n-1} -x_{n-2})} \cdots e^{-ia_{2}(x_{2} -x_{1})} $$ where $a$ is a real positive constant

Comment: Oh, it surely does (for finite $x$ and $y$, of course).